# How to use multiple sync.WaitGroup in a single program

Tags: go, concurrency

In my Go program I start multiple worker groups for every department. 
I want to wait for workers from each department to complete before exiting the program

I cannot use a single WaitGroups because in the actual scenario I may have to end any particular department and need to wait only on that.

This is simplified version of code, but it panics with a message

> panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var wgMap map[string]*sync.WaitGroup

func deptWorker(dName string, id int) {
    defer wgMap[dName].Done()
    fmt.Printf("Department %s : Worker %d starting\n", dName, id)
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    fmt.Printf("Department %s :  Worker %d done\n", dName, id)
}

func department(dName string) {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 1; i <= 3; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go deptWorker(dName, i)
    }
    wgMap[dName] = &wg
}

func main() {
    go department("medical")
    go department("electronics")

    wgMap["medical"].Wait()
    wgMap["electronics"].Wait()
}
```

Comment: Please read the _entire_ stack trace from the panic, and include it in the question. It tells you exactly which line has the problem.

Comment: But the problem is most likely that you never initialized your `wgMap` variable.

Comment: Also note that a map of waitgroups like that is very unconventional, and probably a bad idea. You'll need to protect it with a mutex, which will be very unwieldy.

Comment: Sorry , I missed the make(map..). But adding that too does not help the segfault 

I guess I will have  to change the architecture. I will now have to run multiple processes of go for each department. And orchestrate the processes using a master process

Comment: Please show the full stack trace if you need further help debugging.

Comment: "I will now have to run multiple processes of go for each department." -- Why?

Comment: [ram@ramzhost tests]$ go run wgtest.go   

panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference  

[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x467226]  


goroutine 1 [running]:  

sync.(*WaitGroup).state(...)  
        /usr/lib/golang/src/sync/waitgroup.go:33  
sync.(*WaitGroup).Wait(0x0)  
        /usr/lib/golang/src/sync/waitgroup.go:104 +0x26  
main.main()  
        /home/ram/go/goPickupd/tests/wgtest.go:31 +0xda  
exit status 2

Comment: Maps are not concurrent; you can't modify them from multiple goroutines.  And even if you could, this is still a race condition:  you're immediately accessing the map entries that you expect the goroutines to set later (and this is what is causing your nil deref).  You need to rethink.

Comment: Don't paste a stack trace in a comment. That's impossible to read. Update your question.

Comment: Consider using channel blocking for synchronization here.  `sync.WaitGroup` is the wrong tool for the job - it waits for a collection of goroutines to all finish.  You don't want that.

Answer (score 2):

Two fix nil panic you simply need to use

```
var wgMap = map[string]*sync.WaitGroup{}
```

It will initialize the map. However, in my view, it's better here to create a new abstraction, let's name it 'WaitMap'.

It can be implemented in this way:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type WaitMapObject struct {
    wg map[string]int
    mu sync.Mutex
    cond sync.Cond
}

func WaitMap() *WaitMapObject {
    m := &WaitMapObject{}
    m.wg = make(map[string]int)
    m.cond.L = &m.mu
    return m
}

func (m *WaitMapObject) Wait(name string) {
    m.mu.Lock()
    for m.wg[name] != 0 {
        m.cond.Wait()
    }
    m.mu.Unlock()
}

func (m *WaitMapObject) Done(name string) {
    m.mu.Lock()
    no := m.wg[name] - 1
    if no < 0 {
        panic("")
    }
    m.wg[name] = no
    m.mu.Unlock()
    m.cond.Broadcast()
}

func (m *WaitMapObject) Add(name string, no int) {
    m.mu.Lock()
    m.wg[name] = m.wg[name] + no
    m.mu.Unlock()
}

func deptWorker(dName string, id int, wm *WaitMapObject) {
    defer wm.Done(dName)
    fmt.Printf("Department %s : Worker %d starting\n", dName, id)
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    fmt.Printf("Department %s :  Worker %d done\n", dName, id)
}

func department(dName string, wm *WaitMapObject) {
    for i := 1; i <= 3; i++ {
        wm.Add(dName,1)
        go deptWorker(dName, i, wm)
    }
    wm.Done(dName)
}

func main() {
    wm := WaitMap()

    wm.Add("mediacal",1)
    go department("medical", wm)

    wm.Add("electronics",1)
    go department("electronics", wm)

    wm.Wait("medical")
    wm.Wait("electronics")
}
```

Comment: This second example still contains race conditions that could cause the WaitGroup to panic.

Comment: Yep, I see. https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/sync/waitgroup.go#L44
So the second one is incorrect, I removed it.